# Libavcodec with audio

Tags: c++, linux, audio, libavcodec

I'm learning to program with **libavcodec**. But I'm stuck. All the tutorials I'm using are on video files and I need an audio file. I'm using Ubuntu.

How should I read `AVCodecContext` from an audio stream?
By the way, does anybody know a good tutorial on **libavcodec** with audio? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ffmpeg doc:

http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/api-example_8c-source.html

Is has examples for audio encoding/decoding, and video encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://rodic.fr/blog/libavcodec-tutorial-decode-virtually-any-audio-file/) shows a function that can turn any sound file into an array of `double` samples, with the sampling rate of your choice, using FFMPEG libraries.